# Read Tables from pdf using python

Tags: python, pdf, import

I have the following pdf located [here](http://clerk.house.gov/public_disc/financial-pdfs/2018/10027183.pdf). I have tried, tried and tried again, to read the tables from the pdf. I have listed everything I used so far.

I've tried `tabulua`

```
import tabula

# Read pdf into DataFrame
df = tabula.read_pdf(r"pdf\10027183.pdf")
```

I've tried `textract`

```
import textract
text = textract.process(r"pdf\10027183.pdf", method='pdfminer')
```

And I've tried `tika`

```
from tika import parser

rawText = parser.from_file(r"pdf\10027183.pdf")
rawList = rawText['content'].splitlines()
```

I've tried `pypdf` (PyPDF2 got merged back into pypdf)

```
from pypdf import PdfReader


def get_pdf_content(pdf_file_path):
    reader = PdfReader(pdf_file_path)
    content = "\n".join(page.extract_text().strip() for page in reader.pages)
    content = " ".join(content.split())
    return content


print(get_pdf_content(r"pdf\10027183.pdf"))
```

And I have tried `pdftotext`

```
import pdftotext

with open(r"C:\Users\jfriel\Downloads\10027183.pdf", "rb") as f:
    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

# Iterate over all the pages
for page in pdf:
    print(page)

# Just read the second page
print(pdf.read(2))

# Or read all the text at once
print(pdf.read_all())
```

Is there a way to read in tables from a pdf via python?

EDIT: This is the result for `tabula`, only returns 6 rows the pdf has 11:

[image: results of tabula]

Answer (score 2):

Your document is encrypted. Have a look at the pdf trailer:

```
trailer
<< /Root 2 0 R
   /Info 1 0 R
   /ID [<BC5D1FCFDAF3326F2552B3182CCF1E18> <BC5D1FCFDAF3326F2552B3182CCF1E18>]
   /Encrypt 36 0 R
   /Size 37
>>
```

*/Encrypt* name refers to object number 36 generation 0. Let's use [pdfreader](http://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/) to dive deeper:

```
from pdfreader import PDFDocument
fd = open("10027183.pdf","rb")  
doc = PDFDocument(fd)
obj = doc.locate_object(36,0)
print(obj)
```

you see

```
{'Filter': 'Standard', 
 'V': 2, 
 'R': 3, 
 'Length': 128, 
 'P': -3897, 
 'O': '36451BD39D753B7C1D10922C28E6665AA4F3353FB0348B536893E3B1DB5C579B', 
 'U': '7AFCC66F84741480C7129FC777BB1CDE28BF4E5E4E758A4164004E56FFFA0108'}
```

Value of *V=2* stands for *RC4 or AES algorithms permitting encryption key lengths greater than 40 bits*. In your case it's just an empty password, as Adobe Reader doesn't asks for any password. Nevertheless all the data is encrypted still.

According to [PDF spec](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=63) "Encryption applies to all strings and streams ..." with few exceptions. This means you need to decrypt all streams and strings before data extraction.

Comment: would you recommend decrypting with `pdfReader.decrypt(' ')`? I found that solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822853/how-to-read-this-pdf-form-using-pypdf2-in-python

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm still stuck, will take the same idea and try with a different module